# Hadoop and geospatial connector

Tags: hadoop, geospatial, geoserver, geo, qgis

I am using Cloudera Hadoop, I want to perform Spatial Analytics and need to connect to quantum GIS(QGIS)  for geospatial purposes. I need to know how to connect both QGIS and  Hadoop. Also is there any other way to connect any other GIS systems except ARCGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of free and open-source offerings you can use to achieve your goals.

From the list of [LocationTech projects](https://www.locationtech.org/list-of-projects-solstice), I'd note that [GeoJinni](http://spatialhadoop.cs.umn.edu/) (formerly Spatial Hadoop), [GeoMesa](http://geomesa.org), and [GeoTrellis](http://geotrellis.io/) all work with Hadoop or distributed databases like Accumulo or Cassandra.

More generally, since working with Hadoop means using Java, I'd recommend the [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/) project for processing geo/gis data on the JVM.  GeoTools is used as a library for [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) to publish geospatial data using open standards.  GeoServer and [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) are two of the open alternatives for Arc server products.

As you are looking for alternatives to Arc desktop products, [QGIS](http://qgis.org/) and [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/) are both options.

As a concrete, small examples, I've used the GeoTools library to read shapefiles from HDFS for ingest into GeoMesa with no problems.  Previously, I have looked at serving up geotiffs hosted on HDFS/S3 through GeoServer, and there were a few small changes necessary to wire that up through the stack, but I was able to do it since all the software involved is open-source.

(In full-disclosure, I work on GeoMesa, participate quite a bit with LocationTech projects and some with GeoTools/GeoServer.)

Answer (score 0):

GeoWave is a project that matches the criteria.

The goal of the project is primarily to connect the Hadoop ecosystem with popular GIS software which seems to fit well here. It enables storage/retrieval/analysis of raster/vector/point cloud data within various distributed key-value stores.

Also, the project has installers for Cloudera in addition to other vendors - the latest release with support for Cloudera 5.12.1.

Please keep in mind that I am a GeoWave core contributor.